# Random values in F#

Tags: random, f#

I have F# code something like this:

```
let ran = new System.Random()
let makeVal = ran.NextDouble()
```

Why when I use makeVal do I get the same random number on every call within one run of the app session (i.e. it's not a seed issue).

Comment: I just figured out that makeVal must be a function but how do you make a function with no arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Values in F# are immutable by default. So `makeVal` will not change after the first binding. To get different random values you should call `ran.NextDouble()` again.
For example use the function:

```
let makeVal() = ran.NextDouble()
```